# What is the difference between a name and a label in gparted?

Tags: partition, gparted

When I create a new partition on my disk using GParted, I have the option to set both a name and a label. Some partitions I have already have both, some only a label. If I right-click on an existing partition, I can see separate options to set the partition's name and label.

But what is the difference between the name of a partition and the label of a filesystem? If I can set both and they seem to have a similar effect, does it even matter which one I choose?

Comment: [What is the difference between a partition name and a partition label?](https://superuser.com/q/1099232/241386)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A partition name is a [name given in the GPT](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-name-partition); it's external to the partition itself. A partition label is a label stored inside the filesystem; for example with `ext`-family filesystems, this is the label you can manipulate with [`e2label`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/e2label.8.html).

You can then use filesystem labels or partition names to mount the filesystems, which helps avoid issues with disk name changes. [`mount(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) has more information on this (search for "label"). It probably makes sense for the name to match the label...

Comment: What's the point of a GPT name then? I want my name/label to be durable and am guessing the label is more important.

Comment: In your `/etc/fstab` you can use labels like this: `LABEL=easystore0 /media/easystore0 ext4 defaults 0 0`.

Comment: This `mount` LABEL is misleading (or `gdisk`'s name is misleading): in your example, @Teque5, *LABEL* corresponds to `gparted` *NAME*, and *PARTLABEL* in *fstab* corresponds to *LABEL* in `gparted` (https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Labels/, sorry for a reference in German).

Comment: Which is also curious, I can't set a label in `parted` (and I thought that `gparted`) is simply its graphical interface/wrapper. *mklabel* seems a different command, creating a new disklabel.

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko GParted wraps `parted`, but it also adds file system manipulation features; `parted` has the `name` command to set a partition name, but since it doesn’t know about file systems it doesn’t offer to set the label there.