# How to change partition name (not label)

Tags: partition, gparted

I am using GParted.

It shows partition name and a label.

I found their difference in [What is the difference between a name and a label in gparted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289477/what-is-the-difference-between-a-name-and-a-label-in-gparted)

I found how to change Partition label in [How do I change the “label” reported by lsblk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103569/how-do-i-change-the-label-reported-by-lsblk)

I want to change Partition Name stored in the partition table (not label). How can I do that?

Comment: [Naming a Partition - GParted Manual](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-name-partition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) Make a list of partitions with `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT`

B) Unmount the partition with `umount /xyz -l` where /xyz is the partition to change. 
If it's your boot partition you wish to rename, well, boot with a LiveUSB. The process for making a LiveUSB will vary depending on your distro, but here's a [Windows and Ubuntu](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-the-easy-way/) process.

C) Launch gparted and do `Choose: Partition` then pick */xyz* and select `Name Partition` which will show Set partition name in the /path-to-partition dialog.

D) Type in the name you want to use, then Apply the change.

E) Remount the partition with `/mount /newname -l`.